# проекты в PyCharm

Tags: python

у меня в PyCharm два проекта, хотел узнать как перейти из одного проекта в другой, заранее спасибо

Comment: в каком плане перейти?

Comment: открыть другой проект(не новый а тот что уже был создан)

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: кликаешь в file - open]
нажимаешь file затем open
и выбираешь папку с проектом

Comment: если ответ оказался полезным,отметьте его пожалуйста как решение(галочкой), спасибо